# Notation for optimization over function space

Tags: optimization, notation, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Given a function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Say I want to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the integral over $f(x)g(x)$ is maximized under the constraint that $|f(x)| \leq 1$.

I would write that down, noting that $\mathbb{F}$ is a function space, as

$$
\begin{align}
\max_{f \in \mathbb{F}} & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g(x) dx \,\, \text{ s.t.} \tag{1} \\
&|f(x)| \leq 1 \\
&x \in \mathbb{R} \,.
\end{align}
$$

**Question**: Is this notation ok? I.e. is it correct/good style to write $(1)$ like this?

EDIT: Corrected the equation.

Comment: What does it mean to maximize $f(x)g(x)$? Only for a specific $x$? Or do you essentially look for the function given by $f(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(g(x))$?

Comment: As @HagenvonEitzen said, it is not clear what are you wishing to maximize. Maybe you want to find $f \in \mathbb{F}$ which maximize a **norm** of $f(x)g(x)$. Please, be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I meant the integral over $f(x)g(x)$, I have updated the question.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. After "s.t.", I would write $$|f(x)| \leq 1 ~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: @the_candyman Does that mean the rest of the notation is ok like that?